# Reading Windows 8’s placeholder files with Python

Tags: python-3.x, windows-8, filesystems, python-3.4, onedrive

Windows 8 started using [placeholder files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn323738%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with its OneDrive online storage service. Basically, the user sees an empty placeholder file that will be downloaded on-demand when the user double-clicks it or otherwise try to access it.

How can I read these files with Python? The simple example below shows the problem:

```
os.path.getsize('C:\Users\\User\\OneDrive\online-file.zip')
(…)
OSError: [WinError 1920] The file cannot be accessed by the system:
`C:\Users\\User\\OneDrive\online-file.zip`
```

(Users can work-around the issue by selecting all the files in their OneDrive folder and choosing ”Make available offline“ from their context-menu. There are rumors about this feature being removed from Windows 10.)

Answer (score 0):

This does not seem to be possible. Nor is it relevant much longer as placeholder files will be removed from Windows 10.